# Dynamically import a callable given the full module path?

Tags: python, import, module, introspection

```
>>> import_path('os.path.join')
<function join at 0x22d4050>
```

What is the simplest way to write `import_path` (in Python 2.6 and above)? Assume that the *last* component is always a callable in a module/package.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This seems to be what you want:

```
def import_path(name):
    modname, _, attr = name.rpartition('.')
    if not modname:
        # name was just a single module name
        return __import__(attr)
    m = __import__(modname, fromlist=[attr])
    return getattr(m, attr)
```

To make it work with Python 2.5 and earlier, where `__import__` doesn't take keyword arguments, you will need to use:

```
m = __import__(modname, {}, globals(), [attr])
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
def import_path(name):
  (mod,mem) = name.rsplit('.',1)
  m = __import__(mod, fromlist=[mem])
  return getattr(m, mem)
```

Works at least for

```
>>> import_path('os.walk')
<function walk at 0x7f23c24f8848>
```

and now

```
>>> import_path('os.path.join')
<function join at 0x7f7fc7728a28>
```

Comment: @sridhar fortunately, it's easy enough to work around, see my latest edit

Answer (score 0):

Apparently the following works:

```
>>> p = 'os.path.join'
>>> a, b = p.rsplit('.', 1)
>>> getattr(__import__(a, fromlist=True), b)
<function join at 0x7f8799865230>
```

Comment: Am I not abusing the `fromlist` parameter?